# Can someone explain why doing this causes an error and what is wrong with it?

Tags: c++, pointers

I know that the question was not descriptive, but I hope you guys get understand my question by the end of this.

```
int *p1, *p2;
p1 = new int;
p2 = new int;
*p1=11;
*p2=0;
p2=p1;
cout << *p1 << "  " << *p2 << endl;
delete p1;
delete p2;
```

So I want to know why when you delete p2 does it cause an error and a memory leak?

Thanks!

Comment: `p2=p1;` You've lost the original value of p2 and caused a memory leak.  The error is because you tried to free the same address twice.

Answer (score 0):

It gives you a memory leak because when you assign `*p2` as `*p1` and delete `*p1` , you're essentially deleting `*p2`,but you try to delete a pointer that doesn't exist anymore.